# How to choose point and line thorough it, such that rotating and using points as pivots, it will touch all infinitely many times?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Suppose that you mark a finite collection of points on an infinite plane in such a way that you cannot draw a straight line through any three marked points. We define a windmill to be the following process: draw an infinite straight line on the plane through exactly one of the marked points. Then rotate the line clockwise using the chosen marked point as a pivot until the moving line hits another marked point. At that instant, the new marked point takes over as a pivot, and the line continues to rotate clockwise. This process continues, with new pivots taking over from time to time.

Show that it is possible to select one of the marked points, and choose a starting line through that point at a particular angle, so that the resulting windmill uses every marked point as a pivot on infinitely many occasions.

Comment: Fantastic problem!  But the link goes to something unrelated.

Comment: What effort have you put in. ?

Comment: My initial thoughts: if there are $n$ points, for each pivot there are $n$ equivalence classes of angles for the windmill.  So we have a directed graph on $n^2$ vertices with one outgoing edge per vertex where each edge corresponds to a change in pivot and angle class.  Now we are looking for a cycle which among other conditions must include at least $n$ vertices.

Comment: @dan- the link is for another problem. Could not paste it here hence the link.

Comment: @shailesh- nah I haven't even tried

Answer (score 0):

See [the official solution](https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2011SL.pdf) (page 32).